# QProcess attach to executable ran from script

Tags: bash, qt, qprocess

I'm using QtCreator and I'm trying to create a QProcess that runs a bash script. Inside of that script, after some other commands, an executable is ran.

When I monitor the QProcess, I think when the script finishes, the QProcess is showing as stopped even though the executable launched from that script is still being ran.

Is there a way around this? To somehow attach to the executable launched from that script?

The command I'm executing is:

```sh
xterm -T "Window Title" -geometry 120x24+0+20 -e \
  bash -c 'sudo -E ./executable -s 2>&1 | tee -i log_file.log' &
```

...and I want my parent process to detect when `./executable` finishes -- *without* forcing the xterm to immediately exit when that takes place.

Comment: Without showing details it's hard to say. Easiest fix (and arguably best) is to modify your script to `exec` whatever process it starts, so that process takes over the script's preexisting PID. This is a preferred way for many init systems to track service executables as well.

Comment: Thanks, Charles! Can you clarify on how I can do that? In the bash script, the following command executes the executable. How can I edit it to 'exec'?    xterm -T "Window Title" -geometry 120x24+0+20 -e bash -c 'sudo -E ./executable -s 2>&1 | tee -i log_file.log' &

Comment: After some research, it seems like that is what the & is for at the end of the xterm command? So I'm not sure what the issue is then.

Comment: `&` is the exact opposite of `exec`. An `exec` would tell the shell to run something in the same process. A `&` tells the shell _to spawn off a subprocess_.

Comment: If you wanted to keep the process tree as shallow as possible, an alternative to that might look like: `exec xterm -T "Window Title" -geometry 120x24+0+20 -e bash -c 'exec > >(exec tee -i log_file.log) 2>&1; exec sudo -E ./executable -s'`

Comment: BTW, the reason I got rid of the pipe, replacing it with a [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) is because pipelines _also_ fork off subshells. `foo | tee` creates a new copy of bash that then spawns its own separate children for both `foo` and `tee`; whereas `exec > >(exec tee); exec foo` explicitly puts the `tee` in a child and makes `foo` replace the parent shell.

Comment: BTW -- enough information to solve a question needs to be _included in the question itself_ (not its comments!) to be on-topic here. Consider [edit]ing the question so it contains the information I used in making the above suggestion.

Comment: BTW, -- I'm editing your question to clarify it in a way that invalidates my answer. _Usually_ that's bad practice here (and folks are encouraged to ask a new/different question when the prior interpretation was reasonable and successfully answered), but as the answer's author, I'm okay with it, so... :shrug:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Part 1: Detecting When `xterm` Exits

This is distinct from "Part 2" insofar as it doesn't let your `./executable` finish at one time and your xterm finish at a different, later time. See "Part 2" below for the latter.

The `&` at the end tells the shell not to wait for the `xterm` process (to run it "in the background"). In this case, though, you *want* the shell to wait -- but we can do even better, and make the shell get out of the way completely.

---

#### Step 1: Just take out the `&` at the end.

This will make the process show as running until `xterm` exits -- though to make that happen, the copy of `bash` that is the parent process of the xterm will also be running.

```
xterm -T "Window Title" -geometry 120x24+0+20 -e \
  bash -c 'sudo -E ./executable -s 2>&1 | tee -i log_file.log'
```

---

#### Step 2: Replace the parent-process copy of bash with the xterm process itself

This is done with the `exec` keyword; when you run `exec someprogram`, the shell is replaced in-memory with a copy of `someprogram` (contrast with default behavior, when running `someprogram` starts the program as a subprocess, but unless you used `&` the shell waits for that subprocess to exit before continuing).

This is not only a slight bit of memory savings, but it also means that signals you send will go straight to the `xterm` process, instead of going to the copy of bash that parents it.

```
exec xterm -T "Window Title" -geometry 120x24+0+20 -e \
  bash -c 'sudo -E ./executable -s 2>&1 | tee -i log_file.log'
```

---

#### Step 3: Moving `sudo` and `tee` out of a pipeline

While the above should have solved your immediate process, it still leaves a process tree with more moving parts than necessary: Your Qt program starts `xterm`, xterm starts bash, that copy of bash spawns a pipeline (forking itself into a separate copy of the parent shell on each side), and replaces one side of the pipeline with `sudo` and the other with `tee`.

We can do better by using the bash extension process substitution to make `tee` run as a subprocess, and `sudo -E ./executable` be `exec`'d, replacing the copy of `bash` that `xterm` started:

```
exec xterm -T "Window Title" -geometry 120x24+0+20 -e \
  bash -c 'exec > >(exec tee -i log_file.log) 2>&1;
           exec sudo -E ./executable -s'
```

Note that in `exec > >(...) 2>&1`, we're using a different form of `exec`: When `exec` is given only redirections as arguments, instead of shutting down the current shell and replacing it with another process, it performs those redirections on *the current shell itself*. Thus, when we run `exec 2>&1`, the `2>&1` redirection is performed for the current shell and remains in place until it exits, so we don't need to put another `2>&1` on the `./executable` invocation.

---

## Part 2: Detecting When `./executable` Exits

But what if you want to let the xterm stay open (so the user can read logs) even after `./executable` has finished?

Consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec > >(tee -i log_file.log)
xterm -T "Window Title" -geometry 120x24+0+20 -e tail -n +0 -f log_file.log &
exec sudo -E ./executable -s'
```

Here, we run `xterm` in the background, but `sudo -E ./executable -s` in the foreground (`exec`'d to replace the shell that started it), so the parent process detects when `sudo` exits, not when the `xterm` exits.

Comment: Thanks for that amazing explanation. When I run it, the xterm immediately disappears. I want the xterm window to stay open and show the output of the executable. Any idea why that is happening?

Comment: Immediately disappears _after the executable finishes_, you mean? So, the thing that's going to be tricky about fixing that is letting your parent process know the executable finished separately from letting it know when the xterm exits.

Comment: ...I'm busy with work right now, but when I have a chance to try to build an alternative answer that lets you track when `./executable` finishes, it'll probably rely on having the parent shell wait for a lock to be released.

Comment: I don't think the executable is actually launching with what you sent. If I attempt in terminal, the terminal closes and nothing is launched. If I remove the exec from the front and try again in terminal, nothing is launched and it just returns. I know the executable works fine because if I do ./executable it launches fine in the terminal.

Comment: Hmm. Unfortunately, since nobody but you has `./executable`, that's not something I can easily test.

Comment: BTW, could you provide the actual C++ / Qt code you're using to run the above? I'd be very surprised if the code stated didn't work as-given, but I could conceive of there being problems with how it's embedded in your application causing a similar effect.

Comment: Sure I can, but wouldn't the issue be with the actual command if I can't get it to work in a terminal?

Comment: Ahh -- I didn't grok that. So, for the terminal to close is completely normal, because when you `exec` something else from your interactive shell, you're telling the shell in that terminal _to replace itself_ with the something else in question, so it's no longer running, so it's normal and expected for the terminal to exit the moment whatever you replaced your code with does.

Comment: Now, what you can do to have more of a chance of catching an error is to spawn off a subshell to counteract the effect of that `exec`. You can do that by putting the whole command inside parenthesis: `(exec xterm ...)` -- thus creating a new shell for the `exec` to consume, so your parent shell still stays running.

Comment: Hmm okay, I tried that and didn't really see any errors, it just returned. I'm confused why when I run ./executable it runs fine but with your command it doesn't run.

Comment: As another aside, think about changing `-c` to `-xc` to add some more logging.

Comment: Is `log_file.log` created? (Do we know if xterm is even transiently starting?)

Comment: Aww, shoot, just saw a typo. `exec >(...)` needs to be `exec > >(...)`

Comment: Haha that'll do it. Thanks for much for the great help.

Comment: @CodeDevDave, ...see edit, adding a version where your parent process will detect when `./executable` exits instead of when `xterm` exits.

Comment: @CodeDevDave, ...btw, once you've had a chance to evaluate whether this answer meets your needs, please click the checkbox next to it if it does, or follow up in further comments here to let me know what needs to be corrected if it doesn't.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's working. I'm trying to use the QProcess kill/terminate, and I think it's killing the process that is running the script that runs that xterm, but that xterm still runs. Any idea how to be able to kill that xterm when the script process is killed? Maybe use the same process ID somehow?

Comment: Correct, the last version explicitly makes it so a kill will kill `./executable`, not the xterm. I thought that's what you wanted?

Comment: I didn't incorporate that last version. I currently have the QProcess running the bash script which does a few small tasks and then runs `xterm -T "Window Title" -geometry 120x24+0+20 -e bash -c 'exec > >(exec tee -i log_file.log) 2>&1; exec sudo -E ./executable'` and it seems like when i do QProcess kill/terminate, it may be killing the script process but not the xterm/executable process. I want to kill both.

Comment: Is it just running `xterm ...` and not `exec xterm ...`? You need that `exec` to ensure that the original shell gets replaced with the copy of `xterm`, instead of running it as a subprocess.

Comment: Agh missed that. Adding exec to the front fixed it. Thank you.